# netstat with process name?

Tags: windows-7, powershell, cmd.exe, netstat

Using `netstat -a -o -n`  I can get the list of ports and PID

then I need to go to task manager and add the PID and see who is it.
(pretty frustrating)

[image]

I was wonder if there is a CMD command which does it all ( using `find` , `for` , `powershell`)

so that I could get the process name

Comment: netstat -b as admin, e.g. netstat -abon.  And the name of the exe is below

Comment: I dont see the PID when doing your command

Answer (score 74, accepted):

## Solution

Use the `-b` parameter:

```
  -b            Displays the executable involved in creating each connection or
                listening port. In some cases well-known executables host
                multiple independent components, and in these cases the
                sequence of components involved in creating the connection
                or listening port is displayed. In this case the executable
                name is in [] at the bottom, on top is the component it called,
                and so forth until TCP/IP was reached. Note that this option
                can be time-consuming and will fail unless you have sufficient
                permissions.
```

**Note** The `netstat -b` command will fail unless run from an elevated command prompt.

## Workaround

Filter the process list and find the PID you're interested in:

```
tasklist | findstr /c:"PID"
```

---

## Alternate solution

You can use `Tcpvcon.exe` instead. No admin rights required.

> [Tcpvcon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437) usage is similar to that of the built-in Windows `netstat` utility.

```
Usage: tcpvcon [-a] [-c] [-n] [process name or PID]

 -a Show all endpoints (default is to show established TCP connections).
 -c Print output as CSV.
 -n Don't resolve addresses.
```

Comment: you're the man.

Comment: good answer, just commenting that I think it's amusing how the ms /? documentation even says "this option
can be time-consuming" !  and it's purely a stupidity of windows that it is time consuming. Linux's netstat does its executable name showing fast. And also linux's executable name showing doesn't require root/admin privileges

Comment: how to programatically get tcpvcon.exe, in C++. Does it come as a nuget package?

Comment: I don't see the -b option in the manual: https://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat

Comment: @NathanB You don't need it in Linux: `netstat -vanp tcp | grep 3000`

Answer (score 9):

I think you are looking for [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437) from SysInternals.

Comment: _I was wonder if there is a **CMD** command which does it all_

Comment: Keep going - There is a command-line component of TCPView..

Comment: oh ok. thought maybe someone already done it using for,find etc.

Comment: It should not be too hard to do.. I would bet http://www.robvanderwoude.com has something on it.  Per the TCPView Page - "The TCPView download includes Tcpvcon, a command-line version with the same functionality."

Comment: Very good tool suite.. if it wasn't for msys and sis I'd be using a nix box. :)

Comment: Here is another way to approach this.  Have a look here - http://alternativeto.net/software/tcpviews/

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example for windows using `FOR` to parse `netstat` output then `DO` `tasklist` with `/fi` filter on pid to show process name.

The last find is to remove `tasklist` headers.

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=5 delims= " %i IN (`netstat -ano ^|find "443"`) DO @tasklist /fi "pid eq %i" | find "%i"
```

prints records output like

```
tomcat8.exe.x64               4240 Services                   0    931,864 K
```

Additional fields from `netstat` can be added by adding tokens.

Comment: Pros of this solution including: 1. using `find` to filter out ports (in contrast, although `netstat -b` can provide process name directly, but going through its output to search manually is painful and error-prone); 2. using Windows native commands only, that is more flexible and independent.

Comment: Possible improvement: 1. to use `findstr` with `/R` option instead of `find` to utilize regex for better searching; 2. to use `:443  *[[0-9]"` as the pattern to filter out **local port** only. The whole command could be ``FOR /F "usebackq tokens=5 delims= " %i IN (`netstat -ano ^|findstr /R /C:":443  *[[0-9]"`) DO @tasklist /fi "pid eq %i" | findstr "%i"``

Comment: @DavidPostill or @mark Could you clarify "Additional fields from `netstat` can be added by adding tokens."?

Comment: @YvesSchelpe [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980791/number-of-tokens-limit-in-a-for-command-in-a-windows-batch-script) might bring some light into the dark when it comes to FOR loops and tokens.

Answer (score 3):

If you're fond of using PS, you can fork this code (note: it's super-basic)

```cs
$nets = netstat -ano | select-string LISTENING
foreach($n in $nets){
    # make split easier PLUS make it a string instead of a match object:
    $p = $n -replace ' +',' '
    # make it an array:
    $nar = $p.Split(' ')
    # pick last item:
    $pname = $(Get-Process -id $nar[-1]).ProcessName
    $ppath = $(Get-Process -id $nar[-1]).Path
    # print the modified line with processname instead of PID:
    $n -replace "$($nar[-1])","$($ppath) $($pname)"
}
```

Note that you can try `Path` instead of `ProcessName` to get a full executable path - it won't work with system services though. Also, you may want to append the `ProcessName` to the end of the line instead of replacing the PID value.

Enjoy it ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this...

Process name with time stamp :) in oneliner... no need scripting fast and easy ...

You can change param SYN_SENT by ESTABLISHED or LISTENING

```
filter timestamp {"$(Get-Date -Format G): $_"};netstat -abno 1 | Select-String -Context 0,1 -Pattern LISTENING|timestamp

filter timestamp {"$(Get-Date -Format G): $_"};netstat -abno 1 | Select-String -Context 0,1 -Pattern SYN_SENT|timestamp
```

Comment: I used this with a pattern on the ip:port I wanted to observe. Great snippet!

Answer (score 0):

Very nice Erik Bitemo! I was thinking of adding a variable for the path then I realized you already have that although it was not defined. So the code I reused was:

```
$nets = netstat -ano |select-string LISTENING;
foreach ($n in $nets)
    {
# make split easier PLUS make it a string instead of a match object
    $p = $n -replace ' +',' ';
# make it an array
    $nar = $p.Split(' ')
# pick last item...
    $pname = $(Get-Process -id $nar[-1]).ProcessName
    $ppath = $(Get-Process -id $nar[-1]).Path;
# print the modified line with processname instead of PID
    $n -replace "$($nar[-1])","$($ppath) $($pname)" | where {$pname -like "*GMSVP*"}
     }
```

I was trying to find the processes and services for an application where I used a somewhat different 2 liner.

```
Get-Service | select status,name,displayname,servicename | where {($_.DisplayName -like "myserv*") -or ($_.servicename -like "post*")} | ft -auto

Get-Process | select id, processname,cpu,path,description | where {$_.path -like "*myserv*"} | ft -auto
```

Comment: I edited Erik's question to include your fix, so if you wish, you could delete it from your answer and concentrate on your approach with `GetService` and `Get-Process`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this software too
https://www.smartnetmanager.com/download/snmhe-win64.exe

more details:
https://www.smartnetmanager.com/blog/Advanced/how-to-supervise-the-activities-of-a-process

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).