# What's the netstat command to get the process name and only for a specific port?

Tags: windows, port, netstat

I'm using netstat on Windows 7, I would like to get only the process which are using the port 80 and to get also the name of the process. Not only the PID.

I've found this solution to add the process name [netstat with process name?](https://superuser.com/questions/707249/netstat-with-process-name) but I cannot find how to filter for a specific door.

Comment: this powershell cmdlet seems to do exactly what you need (disclaimer: I have not used it) https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-NetworkStatistics-66057d71

Answer (score 1):

I've found a possible solution on a question which is on StackOverflow (maybe it should be migrated here?)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12010927/196210

It leads to this solution, which is not totally fitting, but better than nothing:

```
netstat -anob | find ":80"
```